# помогите обрезать заголовок, а именно фон

Tags: html, css

```css
#faq {
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 70px;
 padding-bottom: 70px;
}

#faq div {
 width: 25%;
 margin-left: 6%;
 float: left;
 border: 2px solid #DEDEDE;
 border-radius: 7px;
 background-color: #DEDEDE;
 border-bottom: 90px solid #DEDEDE;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)

}

#faq div img {
 width: 94%;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#faq .title {
 font-weight: lighter;
 color: #a3a0ad;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 font-size: 2.2em;

}

#faq .heading {
 color: #7d7d7d;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#faq p {
 font-family: Arimo, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #4a4a4a;
 font-size: 0.95em;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#second {
 margin-top: 10px;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Comfortaa', serif;
 font-weight: lighter;
 background-color: orange;
 border-left: 100px solid orange;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 25%; 
 padding: 10px
 width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<h2><div id="second">Новости о главном...</div></h2>
 <div id="faq">
  <div>
   <img src="img/7.jpg">
   <span class="title"></span><br>
   <span class="heading"></span>
   <p></p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="img/7.jpg">
   <span class="title"></span><br>
   <span class="heading"></span>
   <p></p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="img/7.jpg">
   <span class="title"></span><br>
   <span class="heading"></span>
   <p></p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста сделать нормульный заголовок. Пример: макет и мой сайт[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите Ваш код. А вообще, Вам нужно контейнеру с фоном указать ширину, допустим 60%, а с этой шириной потом поиграться в media запросах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так. Пример на bootstrap.
Если без bootstrap, логика - та же самая.

```css
.bg {
background-color: orange;
width: 75%;
}

.bg h1 {
color: #fff;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="bg">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Название новости</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```